# Bounds on the degree of the vector space formed by the polynomials of degree $D$ that vanish on a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

A paper of Breuillard, Green, & Tao, [Approximate Subgroups of Linear Groups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.1881.pdf), makes the following claim during the proof of Theorem A.3

"The space of polynomials of degree $D$ that vanish on a variety $V$ of degree $D$ [in $\mathbb A^n (k) $] is a vector
space of dimension bounded only by $n$ and $D$."

I'm looking for references to the explicit bounds on the dimension of said vector space in terms of $D$ and $n$, which I cannot seem to find anywhere.

Comment: Right now your statement doesn't make a ton of sense - did you perhaps swap $D$ from being the degree of the variety to the degree of the polynomials?

Comment: @KReiser I have edited the question to exactly quote the linked paper, but it does not seem that they are swapped. Can you expand why you think it doesn't make sense?

Comment: While you are exactly quoting part of the text, you're missing some other information which is important here. The setup to the theorem is "Let $V$ be an irreducible affine variety in $\Bbb A^n(k)$ of degree $D$ over some algebraically closed field $k$." Your statement has to involve $D$, the degree of the variety, in order to make sense.

Comment: I am an idiot! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I misread the question, but the reasoning below should settle the case when $V$ is a hypersurface and can maybe be upgraded to the general case.

I am not aware of any references for this, but I suspect that the authors are referring to something along these lines.

Let $I$ be the ideal $(F)$ generated by the defining polynomial of $V$. Then the space of degree $D$ polynomials vanishing on $V$ is just the degree $D$ part of the radical of $(F)$. But this radical is just the ideal generated by the product of the irreducible factors of $F$.

So let $F=\prod_{i=1}^n f_i^{d_i},$ $f_i$ irreducible. Then your space is just the space of degree $D$ polynomials divisible by $\prod_{i=1}^n f_i.$ And then the maximum dimension is achieved when $F=f^D$ for some $F$ and the dimension of your space is just the dimension of the space of degree $D-1$ polynomials in $n$ variables, which is the binomial coefficient ${n+D-1\choose D-1}.$

But also, if you are only interested in the existence of a bound in terms of $D$ and $n$, why not take just the number of linearly independent polynomials of degree $D$ in $n$ variables?

Comment: Why are you assuming $V$ is only cut out by one equation? The point of the proposition is to show that for *any* degree $d$ variety that no polynomials of degree $>d$ are needed to define $V$ and hence $V$ can be cut out by finitely many equations, and the number of such equations is bounded above by a constant depending only on $d$ and $n$.

Comment: @KReiser You are right, for some reason I read "hypersurface" instead of "variety"